# JavaScript - Input Count Event

Tags: javascript, intervals

I´m trying to write a code that will count from the first textbox to the second one and display that count, counting every second.

I´m just beginning in JS, so I´m not figuring out what is wrong in the code.

```
let firstSubmit = document.getElementById('beginTime');
let secondSubmit = document.getElementById('endTime');
let showElement = document.getElementById("show");

setInterval(function  setUp(){
    let firstNumber = input.value;
    let secondNumber = input.value;
    let result = 0;

    for (set i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++) {
        result += i;
        let newItem = document.createElement("ul");
        newItem.innerHTML = String(i);
        showElement.appendChild(newItem);
    },1000);
}
```

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="count.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body onload="setUp()">

    <h1>Timer</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="beginTime" name="" value="">to <input type="text" id="endTime" name="" value=""> <button type="button" id="CountTo" name="button" onclick="setUp()">Start</button> </p>

    <ul id="show"></ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what count do you want, counting the time (seconds) or the input characters? 
And also, please post html, so we can reproduce it

Comment: the count what is something like this: first input is 6 second is 9, the count will be 6 to 9 every 1 second

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues.   Check out this code.  It's not an answer but it will get you closer.  I commented out part of it because I don't know what you are trying to do.  Every second it will run your loop, so have a way to break out of it!

```
let firstSubmit = document.getElementById('beginTime');
let secondSubmit = document.getElementById('endTime');
let showElement = document.getElementById("show");

setInterval(function() {
  let firstNumber = firstSubmit.value;
  let secondNumber = secondSubmit.value;
  let result = 0;

  for (i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++) {
    result += i;
    console.log(i);
    /*let newItem = document.createElement("ul");
    newItem.innerHTML = String(i);
    showElement.appendChild(newItem);*/
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

So, i have build something up for you. Since you starting with JS i have added comments so you get what's going on in the code.

I left out much checking for correct inputs, just to keep the code short.

First we start with the html-file, that i have altered a little bit, just renaming the ids of the elements and removing empty values:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="count.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="setUp()">
    <h1>Timer</h1>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="beginTimeInput"> to <input type="text" id="endTimeInput">
        <button type="button" id="startButton">Start</button>
    </p>
    <ul id="show"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my count.js version and i hope i dont get you wrong

```
function setUp() {
    // Getting the elements we need
    let firstSubmit = document.getElementById('beginTimeInput');
    let secondSubmit = document.getElementById('endTimeInput');
    let startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
    let showElement = document.getElementById("show");

    // Giving the startButton the onclick functionality
    startButton.onclick = function() {
        // Let us clean up and removing all the content of the showElement
        // to always start "fresh"
        showElement.innerHTML = '';

        // Getting the values of the inputs.
        // Pay attention, the user could have entered not a number or nothing!
        // Empty String will become 0 with Number("")
        let firstNumber = Number(firstSubmit.value);
        let secondNumber = Number(secondSubmit.value);

        // We do a quick check if the user enters zwo numbers, then the counter
        // is allowed to start, otherwise we don't start counting. This is not the
        // best solution, but you just started with JS so we keep it simple.
        // isNaN is a function to check if the passed value is not a number.
        // !isNan means then "is not not a number"... i hope you get the point
        // If firstNumber and secondNumber are the same, we also don't start.
        if (!isNaN(firstNumber) && !isNaN(secondNumber) && firstNumber != secondNumber) {
            // Set the result to firstNumber - 1, so at the first interval tick
            // it get increased to firstNumber and then is added in
            let result = firstNumber - 1;

            // Set an interval to count from firstNumber up to secondNumber
            // adding a new LI-Element to the showElement (in this case an UL-Element)
            // intervalID is a Number, representing the ID value of the timer
            // that is set. After counting is done we use this ID to stop the created
            // interval, so it will not count/tick/fire in the background when the
            // job is already done.
            let intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                result++;

                // Creating the new LI-Element and append it to the showElement
                let newItem = document.createElement('li');
                newItem.innerText = String(result);
                showElement.appendChild(newItem);

                // Check if we reached the secondNumber, if so, lets stop the interval
                // by using the intervalID we stored before
                if (result >= secondNumber) {
                    clearInterval(intervalID);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

See it in action:

```js
function setUp() {
  // Getting the elements we need
  let firstSubmit = document.getElementById('beginTimeInput');
  let secondSubmit = document.getElementById('endTimeInput');
  let startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
  let showElement = document.getElementById("show");

  // Giving the startButton the onclick functionality
  startButton.onclick = function() {
    // Let us clean up and removing all the content of the showElement
    // to always start "fresh"
    showElement.innerHTML = '';

    // Getting the values of the inputs.
    // Pay attention, the user could have entered not a number or nothing!
    // Empty String will become 0 with Number("")
    let firstNumber = Number(firstSubmit.value);
    let secondNumber = Number(secondSubmit.value);

    // We do a quick check if the user enters zwo numbers, then the counter
    // is allowed to start, otherwise we don't start counting. This is not the
    // best solution, but you just started with JS so we keep it simple.
    // isNaN is a function to check if the passed value is not a number.
    // !isNan means then "is not not a number"... i hope you get the point
    // If firstNumber and secondNumber are the same, we also don't start.
    if (!isNaN(firstNumber) && !isNaN(secondNumber) && firstNumber != secondNumber) {
      // Set the result to firstNumber - 1, so at the first interval tick
      // it get increased to firstNumber and then is added in
      let result = firstNumber - 1;

      // Set an interval to count from firstNumber up to secondNumber
      // adding a new LI-Element to the showElement (in this case an UL-Element)
      // intervalID is a Number, representing the ID value of the timer
      // that is set. After counting is done we use this ID to stop the created
      // interval, so it will not count/tick/fire in the background when the
      // job is already done.
      let intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        result++;

        // Creating the new LI-Element and append it to the showElement
        let newItem = document.createElement('li');
        newItem.innerText = String(result);
        showElement.appendChild(newItem);

        // Check if we reached the secondNumber, if so, lets stop the interval
        // by using the intervalID we stored before
        if (result >= secondNumber) {
          clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="count.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="setUp()">
  <h1>Timer</h1>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="beginTimeInput"> to <input type="text" id="endTimeInput">
    <button type="button" id="startButton">Start</button>
  </p>
  <ul id="show"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, this helped a lot. If I want to set a key to pause the countdown and resume, is the keydown event? Like, if I want to set the space bar to pause the count and press space bar again to resume.